# Is there an efficient way to dynamically compare a static list of properties in Swift?

Tags: swift, iphone, boilerplate

I'm relatively new @ using Swift, so this might have an obvious answer. At any rate, I'm trying to avoid writing bucketloads of boiler plate for `Equatable` implementations, and I'm wondering:

If I have a list of properties I want to compare, is there some efficient equivalent of this approximate-pseudocode that works fast and correctly:

```
func .... ==  .... -> Bool {
    let leftMirror = Mirror(reflecting: lhs)
    let rightMirror = Mirror(reflecting: rhs)
    let propertiesToCompare = [a list of strings to test]

    for lchild in leftMirror.children {
        if (lchild.label in propertiesToCompare) {
            guard lchild.value == rMirror.descendant(lchild.label.value) else { return false }
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: "avoid writing bucketloads of boiler plate for Equatable implementations," Are you aware that it's compiler synthesized, in newer version of Swift ( I think after 4.1 or something like that)

Comment: Interesting.  If it's synthesized, then, why doesn't xcode mark it as such / hide it?

Comment: I don't understand your question, why doesn't xcode mark or hide *what*, exactly?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. Are you saying https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/Sourcery is no longer relevant, as of Swift 4.1?

Comment: Like, is there a way I can tell the newer swift compilers which properties to include in the synthesized == implementation?

Comment: I'm afraid not, it's fixed to either equating everything, or nothing. Otherwise you have to spell it all out yourself :/